# Extra Icon at the Dock

Tags: appcenter, plank, launcher

When I open Android Studio (installed through appcenter), an extra cog icon appear at the end of the dock. Why is that.

[image]

Comment: Nothing to worry about. When I run steam and start a game the same thing happens.

Comment: What is steam ?

Comment: Steam is a gaming platform. If you want to play games that's the place.

Comment: It sounds waste of time. I would rather watch youtube videos.